# Break executed when it shouldn't

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, break

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        if (false) break;
}
```

Compiled and executed with VS 2010 (same issue in VS 2008). I put a breakpoint at the last line (closing bracket) and look via debugger into variable i. This code leaves i at 0. Why?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        if (false) break;;
}
```

After this - please notice the second semicolon after break - i is 50 as expected.

Can someone please explain this strange behaviour to me?

Comment: How do you check the value of `i`?

Comment: Are compiler optimizations on?

Comment: The extra semicolon in the second example is an empty statement _outside_ the loop, so it means the two loops are just the same from the compilers point of view.

Comment: Just checked various possible combinations with `g++`, always see `50`. Of course, you didn't post a complete example, so I can't be sure my code is identical to yours... Maybe you print it out in some odd way..?

Comment: @Kiril Kirov: checked via debugger

Comment: @sharptooth: also occurs with compiler optimizations disabled

Comment: Try to make a complete example, that can be tested by others. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: void main() 
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) if(false) break;
    }

I set a breakpoint at the last line (the closing bracked) and look via debugger into the variable i.

Comment: @KoljaBeigel To put code in comments, surround it in backticks (just below Esc key), or better yet, edit your original post.

Comment: I can not reproduce this. I get the right result. Just try returning i from a function (or even from main)

Comment: This code doesn’t compile on a conforming compiler, as it’s invalid C++.

Comment: Edited the original post (complete code incl main).

Comment: If you press f10 again, it goes to the beginning of the loop as expected. Seems like this is just a problem with the pdbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MSVC10, this is reproducible. I checked the disassembly. It seems a problem in the pdb file generation. The jump instruction to go back to the beginning of the loop is mixed with the next source line, that's it.
If you press step to next line, it will go back to the beginning of the for loop from the return statement and execute the loop 50 times as expected.
[image: See the code].

Comment: A workaround is to put braces around the body of the loop, with the closing brace on its own line. The code that returns to the start of the loop then becomes associated with the closing brace.

Comment: If that's reproducible it can be filed via connect.microsoft.com so that it is fixed in future versions.

Answer (score 3):

This code doesn’t compile on a conforming compiler, as it’s invalid C++ (`void main`).

That said, the resulting value of `i` is irrelevant: the compiler can do whatever it wants.

The reason is that `i` is never read outside the loop (which itself provably has no effect) and not declared `volatile` so the compiler is trivially able to prove that there is no observable side-effect, no matter the value of `i`.

Comment: It appears that 'i' is being read in the for condition (i < 50), but the for loop is being optimized out since 'i' is not being read anywhere else.

Comment: @Nick Yes, that’s what I meant. Clarifying …

Comment: Edited original post and changed the main method.

Comment: Sounds plausible. In the "real life code" the testing condition is not always false though and the compiler has no chance for optimizing it. Nevertheless the for-loop always seems to be exited after one cycle.

Comment: It only appears it actually breaks. Try changing `i = 0` to `i = -100` in the for loop, i.e.`for (i = -100; i < 50; i++)`. It is very likely `i` will still be zero in your debugger.

Comment: Or betteryet, just change `break` to `continue`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the generated assembly code with `objdump -d -S` we can see a possible reason that GDB jumps over the loop:

```
0000000000400584 <main>:
int main()
{
  400584:   55                      push   %rbp
  400585:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    volatile int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  400588:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
  40058f:   eb 09                   jmp    40059a <main+0x16>
  400591:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  400594:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  400597:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
  40059a:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  40059d:   83 f8 04                cmp    $0x4,%eax
  4005a0:   0f 9e c0                setle  %al
  4005a3:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
  4005a5:   75 ea                   jne    400591 <main+0xd>
  4005a7:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
        if (false)
            break;
}
  4005ac:   c9                      leaveq 
  4005ad:   c3                      retq   
  4005ae:   90                      nop
  4005af:   90                      nop
```

Even when though compiled with optimizations turned off (`-O0` flag to g++) no code is actually generated for the loop body. This might means that GDB will see the loop as a single statement, and will not step through the loop properly.

I used GCC version 4.4.5, and GDB version 7.0.1.